# GitHub 'HTTP' Permission denied with 'Git' Success

Tags: git, github

I am trying to use my new github account in the same computer.
When I use 'http' as url it keeps denied my access, however, if I use 'git@' it goes well.
Can anyone tell me the reason?

```
$git remote add origin http://github.com/curusr/CTCI.git
$git push origin master
remote: Permission to curusr/CTCI.git denied to prevusr.
```

But if I do the following.

```
$git remote add origin2 git@github.com:curusr/CTCI.git
```

The push succeed.
And, if I use ssh I get the message.
Hi curusr! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

Comment: http is unauthenticated, just always use ssh if you have a github account anyway

Comment: Thx, I was just confused why it worked previously. I guess I'll just stick with ssh.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've set up Git to use SSH locally, so that's why using a url of the format `git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git` works when you push to it.

GitHub probably doesn't allow push (write) access to repos without authentication, which would explain why trying to push with an HTTP url instead of HTTPS or SSH would fail. If GitHub did allow HTTP push access, then ***anyone*** would be able to push code to your remote repo, without authentication!

Comment: The difference between HTTP or HTTPS would not decide about the authentication. I can easily do authentication via non-secure HTTP. The difference is that HTTPS actually secures the communication, so the login data and the transferred data is safer. You are right though, that GitHub does not allow pushing via HTTP—that’s not because they couldn’t authenticate you that way though.